# php pagination get a mysql error

Tags: php, pagination, mysql-error-1064

I have a page in which i have added pagination inside an album and works quite ok, but i have found a problem though. I typed in the url some values, for checking purposes, in pages like ?page=a or ?page=0.1 (with integers like ?page=1, ?page=2 etc doesn't have any errors)and displayed this error:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-15 , 15' at line 7"

so if a user tries to put values like these, wouldn't that be a security problem? How could apply somekind of check and prevent this?

Here is my code

```
$per_page = 15;
$pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`album_id`) FROM `albums` ", $connection);
$pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);

$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;

$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
$query_get_imgs = "SELECT `albums`.`album_id`,
                                `albums`.`album_name`,
                                COUNT(`images`.`image_id`) AS `image_count`
                                FROM `albums` LEFT JOIN `images`
                                ON `albums`.`album_id`= `images`.`album_id`
                                GROUP BY `albums`.`album_id` ORDER BY `albums`.`album_id` DESC LIMIT {$start} , {$per_page} ";
$get_imgs = mysql_query($query_get_imgs, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_get_imgs = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_imgs);
$totalRows_get_imgs = mysql_num_rows($get_imgs);
```

Comment: validate the `page` value  using `is_numeric`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this problem, you need to check that `$start` is greater or equal than 0.

Comment: ok, so i have to make sure that $start is > 0 ?? how actually can i apply this check in this $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

Comment: `$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
$start = $start > 0 ? $start : 0;` or `$start = $page > 0 ? ($page - 1) * $per_page : 0;`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$page = (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `if($page<1)`? (But no, it's not a *security* risk).

Answer (score 0):

when page start from 0

```
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

$start = -15 and that is wrong because the index start from 0
```

you need to give the 0 a special case

Comment: ok, so i have to make sure that $start is > 0 ?? how actually can i apply this check in this $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

Answer (score 0):

And another variation of the same theme ;-)

```
$start = (max(1, $page)-1) * $per_page;
```